# MySQL - Store Procedure no afecta ningun registro

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedure con el cual quiero actualizar algunos registros mediante un LOOP. Aquí el detalle es actualizar respetando el ordenamiento y la cantidad de registros a actualizar, como limite el valor de TOTAL_POR_ASIGNAR ya que son varios empleados para el mismo lugar y se deben de repartir.

Revisando la lógica funcionaria correctamente e probado ejecutar cada consulta y UPDATE por separado y funciona correctamente pero el detalle es cuando corro el procedure no me realiza nada, no se si se deba a un error en el código o simplemente no se permite realizar algo así en un procedimiento.

Les comparto parte del codigo:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE lugar VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE empleado VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE total INT; 

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT LUGAR,EMPLEADO,TOTAL_POR_ASIGNAR FROM asignacion.ft_asignacion WHERE TOTAL_POR_ASIGNAR > 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO lugar,empleado,total;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    UPDATE asignacion.bolsa
    SET B55 = empleado
    WHERE B1 IN (
        SELECT B1 FROM (
            SELECT B1
            FROM asignacion.bolsa
            WHERE B13 = lugar AND B55 = ""
            ORDER BY B53 ASC
            LIMIT total
        ) tmp
    );
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
```

END

Comment: Prueba añadiendo ´COMMIT;´ antes de la línea ´END LOOP;´

Comment: @NEOhitokiri Lo acabo de intentar pero nada, sigue sin actualizar algún registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comento sobre mi propia pregunta para publicar la solución.

El problema que tenia era el nombre de las variables:

- lugar
- empleado

Supongo que al ser igual que las columnas de la tabla **ft_asignacion** (LUGAR,EMPLEADO) tenia conflictos y me dejaban con valor de **NULL** las variables, solamente cambie el nombre a:

- lugar2
- empl

Con esto el proceso funciona correctamente:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE lugar2 VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE empl VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE total INT; 

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT LUGAR,EMPLEADO,TOTAL_POR_ASIGNAR FROM asignacion.ft_asignacion WHERE TOTAL_POR_ASIGNAR > 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO lugar2,empl,total;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    UPDATE asignacion.bolsa
    SET B55 = empl
    WHERE B1 IN (
        SELECT B1 FROM (
            SELECT B1
            FROM asignacion.bolsa
            WHERE B13 = lugar2 AND B55 = ""
            ORDER BY B53 ASC
            LIMIT total
        ) tmp
    );
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
END
```